# Finding place by HERE id

Tags: here-api

I try to get HERE place information by place id. Something like

`https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/276u337n-1e7e6de955674eddb3ba8662d8a83bac?app_id={XXXX}&app_code={YYYY}`

returns

> It is not permissible to use URL templating. Please follow the Places
>   API Developer Guide:
>   https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/required-user-flow.html

I understand the use and concept of URL templating but the link does not provide me with the information to get place information by Here ID. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Short disclaimer: I work in the team around HERE places API.

The querying for place ids directly is not supported because they might change over time and become stale. So the idea is that clients don't store them over longer periods of time.

The basic entrypoint to the Places API is to do a search first, e.g.
[/discover/search](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=52.531%2C13.3848&q=Total&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) and follow the `href` fields in the response items to get to the details of a place.

I am not quite sure what your use case is but if the above doesn't work in your flow, I would suggest extracting the sharing ids. You can find those inside the place details in the response field 'view', it is the part starting with `s-`. 
But to get to the place details you will have to do a search at one point and follow the `href`. The sharing id contains more information than just the place id so it should resolve more reliably.

Once you have obtained sharing ids, you can you use 
[the lookup endpoint](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?source=sharing&id=s-Yz1wZXRyb2wtc3RhdGlvbjtpZD0yNzZ1MzM3bi0xZTdlNmRlOTU1Njc0ZWRkYjNiYTg2NjJkOGE4M2JhYztsYXQ9NTIuNTc2MjY7bG9uPTEzLjMxNDk5O249VE9UQUw7bmxhdD01Mi41NzYyNjtubG9uPTEzLjMxNDk5O3BoPSUyQjQ5MzA0MTcwMzAyMztoPTRhN2QyZQ&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg). Be prepared to follow a 302 HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

This API might help: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-lookup-brief.html

For some reason, while Places API does not support querying by identifiers they return, Geocoding API is perfectly well with that. Example:

```
GET https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup?id=here:pds:place:276u0vhj-b0bace6448ae4b0fbc1d5e323998a7d2&apiKey={API_KEY}
```

(The `apiKey` parameter is not documented there, but it works.)