# Proper way of sharing places between platforms

Tags: here-api

I am using Here Maps on mobile platforms via the iOS and Android SDKs. My plan is to allow a user to search for nearby places via the Places API and to share this place with a backend service that is backed by the Places Rest API. I am wondering what I need to share from the mobile platforms with the backend service for consistency.

There was a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001526/finding-place-by-here-id/46448181#46448181) from 2017 but I am not sure if it is still applicable since it appears we can lookup places by their "unique ID's" below.

From the iOS client, I am able to store both the "share ID" portion of  `viewUrl` and `uniqueId` from `NMAPlace` to lookup the `NMAPlace` again via:

- `NMAPlaces.sharedInstance().createLookupRequest(referenceIdentifier: shareId, source: NMAPlacesSourceSharing)` or
- `NMAPlaces.sharedInstance().createLookupRequest(referenceIdentifier: uniqueId, source: NMAPlacesSourceSharing)`

**and both yield the same result**.

When using the Rest API, I can do either:

- https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?app_id=abc&app_code=xyz&source=sharing&id=shareId
- https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?app_id=abc&app_code=xyz&source=sharing&id=uniqueId

**and both yield the same result**.

My question boils down to what I share between the mobile applications and the backend - the "uniqueId" or "shareId"?

Answer (score 1):

For sharing use cases, the recommended id is the "share ID" in the `viewURL`.

Please see the docs for `-createLookupRequestWithReferenceIdentifier:inSource:`
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAPlaces.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAPlaces(im)createLookupRequestWithReferenceIdentifier:inSource: